# How can I make this multiline regex matching pattern non greedy?

Tags: regex, xml, multiline

I have the following string:

```
<SomeXmlProperty att="abc" 
att2="def"
att3="ghi"/>
<SomeXmlProperty att4="jkl" 
att5="mno"
att6="pqr"><SomeXmlProperty>
<SomeXmlProperty att="stu" 
att3="vwx"
att6="yz"   
/>
```

I am needing to match the elements with self closing tags.
I have tried using both `<SomeXmlProperty((.|\n|\r)*)\/>` and `<SomeXmlProperty((.|\n|\r)*?)\/>` which get close but the middle element still gets matched. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `<SomeXmlProperty((?:(?!<SomeXmlProperty)[\w\W])*?)\/>`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use a character class that excludes `<`s instead to avoid matching multiple tags:

```
<SomeXmlProperty[^<]*\/>
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/VEyVg1/1